# Queue implementation, peek() method error

Tags: java, package

Here is my code to implement a `Queue`. There is a problem while running the code, It's showing a runtime error in the `peek()` method.

```
public class Queue {
int size;
int frontIndex;
int backIndex;
int arr[];

Queue()
{
 size = 5;
 frontIndex =-1;
 backIndex = -1;
 arr = new int[size];
}
public int peek() {
return arr[frontIndex];
}
 public void enqueue(int data)
{
    if(isFull())
    {
    System.out.println("Queue is overflow");
    }
    else
    {   
    System.out.println("Insert " + data);
    backIndex ++;
    arr[backIndex]=data; 
    }
 }
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    Queue queue = new Queue();  
    queue.enqueue(15);
    queue.enqueue(18);      
 System.out.println("Front element of queue is " + queue.peek()); 
  } 
 }
```

This is the error that I get:

```
"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 out of bounds for length 5 "
```

Comment: You increment `backIndex` when you enqueue an item in the queue BUT in the `peek` method, you are accessing `frontIndex` which is -1, hence the out of bounds exception. You forgot to update `frontIndex` inside the `enqueue` method.

Comment: You init `frontIndex` with -1 and `peek` tries to access the array on that index. So, totally expected. Why do _you_ **not** expect this?

Comment: @Fildor  yup ,you are right ,I understood where I had made my mistake. Thanks for support.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please indent your code. Proper indentation is not optional, but essential for readability. When you post on SO, please make it as easy as possible for people to help you. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are never updating your `frontIndex`.

What you could do is:

Set `frontIndex` to 0 instead of -1, so that `peek()` doesn't throw an Exception before you get the first element out of the queue. I guess the reasoning behind initialising it with -1 was, that you would increment before getting an element from the queue. This is problematic when you are trying to `peek()` into the queue before accessing its first element.

The workaround is simply to initialise `frontIndex` with 0, and then incrementing it **after** you get a value out of the queue.

If `peek()` is supposed to actually take the value out of the queue, simple increase `frontIndex` in the `peek` method:

```
public int peek() {
    frontIndex++;
    return arr[frontIndex];
}
```